# Unbuildable project due to circular dependencies

Tags: maven, circular-dependency

My project consists of 2 maven modules *A* and *B* with 3 submodules:

*A*

- *aApi*
- *aSpec*
- *aSrv*

*B*

- *bApi*
- *bSpec*
- *bSrv*

References:

- *A* (*aSrv*) is using model from *B* (*bApi*)
- *B* (*bSrv*) is using model from *A* (*aApi*)

I obviously have an error when building my project due to circular dependency (*A* is not building because it needs something from *B* and *B* is not building because it needs something from *A*). I think logically my module division makes sense but what's the best approach here for
making it buildable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve cyclic dependency in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468525/how-to-resolve-cyclic-dependency-in-maven)

Comment: It's a quite different scenario, in my case if we look at A and B as a whole there is a circular dependency but at the submodule perspective, there isn't. So I thought it's possible to organize somehow the build process that A and B will build properly.

Answer (score 0):

If your projects are so tightly coupled, it would be best to just construct one multi-module project with all 6 modules.

In the given form, the project cannot be built. Because multi-module projects should be built completely (not just parts of it), your circular dependency is a logical problem that needs to be resolved (not just a technical one).